# How to run the newly created notebook "anonymously"?

Tags: debugging

How to test the autonomy of all calculations on .nb, i.e. run it so that it does not use existing variables from other .nb executables? And if it refers to a variable you did not create yourself to point out to it?

*When I create a small project in Mathematice, I first test a lot of procedures and functions on the secondary .nb (functionality, correctness of writing and grammar ...) I will only transfer them to the main .nb when I'm sure of their correctness.*

*When I finish working and I close and store my laptops, I want to test if any calculation was accidentally left out.*

Comment: You could run it in a second kernel created as explained here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124462/8822

Comment: You can also use different variables for different notebooks  as explained here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/853/is-there-a-way-to-separate-variables-between-multiple-notebooks

Comment: I often had difficulties with cross-talk among open notebooks using the \`Global context.  So, I now always run Mathematica with "Notebooks Default Context" (in the "Evaluation" menu) set to "Unique to This Notebook".  If you find this satisfactory, you can use the "Options Inspector" to apply this setting to all future notebooks.