# If the Mathematica is running the code in one kernel, how can I run another code in other kernel?

Tags: kernel

If one kernel (with KernelID 1) is running the code which will take a long time, how can I run another code in other kernels (KernelID 2) in the process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48457/11467]

Comment: In particular see the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124462. You can select the kernel for each notebook separately in the menu Evaluate->Notbook's Kernel -> <<what kernel you like>>. You may have to set up a kernel first with Evaluate->Kernel Configuration Options. In principle, this allows you also to set up and tp select a kernel on a remote machine (but I have not tried it yet).

Comment: The simplest is to start MMA a second time. This works under Windows, I do not know if it works under Unix.

Comment: @Daniel Starting a new kernel as suggested above is slightly faster :) .